# Dynamic UIPopoverController Size?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController in my app which simply displays two UILabels beside each other with a list of words in each of them. However sometimes there are only a couple of words in each list meaning there is tons of blank space in the popover view.

How can I make it so that the popover view in at least height dynamically adapts to how many lines of words there are in my label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If text in label is specified before popover shows, you can achieve this by using similar code in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ...

    CGFloat height = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font 
                                     forWidth:label.frame.size.width 
                                lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode].height;

    // This calculates only height of the label, you may want to add some margins, etc. 

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height);
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;
}
```

Comment: I can see how this would work, but sadly it isn't. Im getting a very narrow thin view. When I fill my labels with words, I add a word, then new line it with \n and again and again etc. When you pass the text value of the label, might it not detect the line breaks?

Comment: For what I'm aware, `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` doesn't respect newline characters. You should try instead `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:`